# Why when the menu is fully expanded and i scroll down on mobile devices the menu collapses

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I was wondering why when the menu is fully expanded and when on mobile devices you scroll down the menu actually collapses. Please help.
Link to the site,, be aware i have not done much yet. [explorenewzealand.net](http://explorenewzealand.net)
I will put the code down below if required. Just ask and i will comment with the code that you want.
Thank you very much and any help would be appreciated

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
    <title>Home|Tourist Advice|Explore New Zealand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">


    </head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href=""><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="aboutnewzealand.html"><span>About New Zealand</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>South Island</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="aboutnewzealand/marlborough.html"><span>Marlborough</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutnewzealand/nelson.html"><span>Nelson</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutnewzealand/westcoast.html"><span>West Coast</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutnewzealand/canterbury.html"><span>Canterbury</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutnewzealand/queenstown-lakes.html"><span>Queenstown Lakes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutnewzealand/fiordland.html"><span>Fiordland</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutnewzealand/otago.html"><span>Otago</span></a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="aboutnewzealand/southland.html"><span>Southland</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="accommodation.html"><span>Accommodation</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>South Island </span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="accommodation/marlborough.html"><span>Marlborough</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="accommodation/nelson.html"><span>Nelson</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="accommodation/westcoast.html"><span>West Coast</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="accommodation/canterbury.html"><span>Canterbury</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="accommodation/queenstown-lakes.html"><span>Queenstown Lakes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="accommodation/fiordland.html"><span>Fiordland</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="accommodation/otago.html"><span>Otago</span></a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="accommodation/southland.html"><span>Southland</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="attractions.html"><span>Attractions &amp; Activities</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>South Island </span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="attractions&amp;activities/marlborough.html"><span>Marlborough</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="attractions&amp;activities/nelson.html"><span>Nelson</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="attractions&amp;activities/westcoast.html"><span>West Coast</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="attractions&amp;activities/canterbury.html"><span>Canterbury</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="attractions&amp;activities/queenstown-lakes.html"><span>Queenstown Lakes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="attractions&amp;activities/fiordland.html"><span>Fiordland</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="attractions&amp;activities/otago.html"><span>Otago</span></a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="attractions&amp;activities/southland.html"><span>Southland</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub last"><a href="dining.html"><span>Dining</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>South Island </span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="dining/marlborough.html"><span>Marlborough</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="dining/nelson.html"><span>Nelson</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="dining/westcoast.html"><span>West Coast</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="dining/canterbury.html"><span>Canterbury</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="dining/queenstown-lakes.html"><span>Queenstown Lakes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="fiordland.html"><span>Fiordland</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="otago.html"><span>Otago</span></a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="southland.html"><span>Southland </span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #3db2e1;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #69c4e8, #21a1d4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #69c4e8, #21a1d4);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #69c4e8, #21a1d4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #69c4e8, #21a1d4);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #69c4e8, #21a1d4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 #1f97c7, inset 0 -3px 3px #1f9acc, inset 0 2px 2px #9ad7ef, inset 1px 0 2px #22a4d9, inset -1px 0 2px #22a4d9, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17), 2px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -2px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #cae5fd;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 17.5px;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: #3db2e1;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #209ed0, inset 0 2px 1px #7fcceb;
  background-size: 36px 36px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:after {
  background-position: 0 -18px;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 11px;
  top: 25.5px;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99;
}
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  border-top-color: #19799f;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  -o-transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  transition: top .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  top: 91px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 51px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 40px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 178px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 178px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3db2e1;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #cae5fd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #88d0ed;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 #27a9de, inset 0 -3px 3px #1f9acc, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: 12px;
  top: 9.5px;
  background: #3db2e1;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #209ed0, inset 0 2px 1px #7fcceb;
  background-size: 36px 36px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 12px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:after {
  background-position: 0 -18px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  top: 15.5px;
  right: 16px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  top: 15.5px;
  right: auto;
  left: 16px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #1c89b5;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #1c89b5;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    padding-left: 12.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding: 14px 25px 14px 27.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 42.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 57.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 12.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 53px;
    height: 53px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 41px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul .submenu-button:after,
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 12.5px;
    top: 12.5px;
    display: block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #3db2e1;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #58bde5 0%, #4ab7e3 25%, #2babde 50%, #58bde5 75%, #4ab7e3 100%);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #209ed0, inset 0 2px 1px #7fcceb;
    background-size: 56px 56px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  }
  #cssmenu ul .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after,
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    background-position: 0 -28px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 6.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before,
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 22.5px;
    top: 25.5px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 19.5px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before,
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    border-top-color: #19799f;
  }

}

.css3menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #111;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #2da2de 0%,
        #2da2de 16%,
        #2da2de);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom,
        from(#2da2de),
        color-stop(0.16, #2da2de),
        to(#2da2de));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #2da2de 0%,
        #2da2de 16%,
        #2da2de 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #2da2de 0%,
        #2da2de 16%,
        #2da2de 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        #2da2de 0%,
        #2da2de 16%,
        #2da2de 100%);
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 0px solid #2795ce;
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.0),
        inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(254,255,255,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.0),
        inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(254,255,255,1);
    box-shadow:
        0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.0),
        inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(254,255,255,1);
}
.css3menu li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.css3menu li:first-child{
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    border-left: 0px;
}
.css3menu li:last-child{
    border-right: 0px;
}
.css3menu li:hover{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        rgba(255, 56, 92, 0.10) 0%,
        rgba(37, 139, 193, 0.10) 25%,
        rgba(45, 162, 222, 0.10) 50%,
        rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10) 75%,
        rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10));
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom,
        from(rgba(255, 56, 92, 0.10)),
        color-stop(0.25, rgba(37, 139, 193, 0.10)),
        color-stop(0.50, rgba(45, 162, 222, 0.10)),
        color-stop(0.75, rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10)),
        to(rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10)));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(
        top,
        rgba(255, 56, 92, 0.10) 0%,
        rgba(37, 139, 193, 0.10) 25%,
        rgba(45, 162, 222, 0.10) 50%,
        rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10) 75%,
        rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(
        top,
        rgba(255, 56, 92, 0.10) 0%,
        rgba(37, 139, 193, 0.10) 25%,
        rgba(45, 162, 222, 0.10) 50%,
        rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10) 75%,
        rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(255, 56, 92, 0.10) 0%,
        rgba(37, 139, 193, 0.10) 25%,
        rgba(45, 162, 222, 0.10) 50%,
        rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10) 75%,
        rgba(48, 180, 250, 0.10) 100%);
}
.css3menu li:active{
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.10);
}
.css3menu a{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow:
        0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
        0px 0px 7px rgba(254,255,255,0.1);
}
.css3menu a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.css3menu a:active{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.css3menu li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}
.css3menu li:active > ul{
    display: block;
}
.css3menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #ffffff 0%,
        #ebf4c3);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom,
        from(#ffffff),
        to(#ebf4c3));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #ffffff 0%,
        #ebf4c3 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #ffffff 0%,
        #ebf4c3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        #ffffff 0%,
        #ebf4c3 100%);
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #6d8000;
}
.css3menu ul li{
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 1px 0 #777777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 1px 0 #777777;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 1px 0 #777777;
}
.css3menu ul li:first-child{
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}
.css3menu ul li:last-child{
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.css3menu ul li:hover{
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.10);
}
.css3menu ul li:active{
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.10);
}
.css3menu ul a{
    color: #141414;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 180px;
}
.css3menu ul a:hover{
    color: #141414;
}
.css3menu ul a:active{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.css3menu ul li:first-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.css3menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after{
    border-bottom-color: #04acec;
}
.css3menu ul li:last-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.css3menu:after{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}


.mainmenuicondata {
    line-height: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.submenuicondata {
    line-height: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.mainmenuicondata.icon1 {
    padding-right: 18px;
    background: url("bottom.png") no-repeat 0 -4px;
    background-size: 8px 8px;
    background-position: right center;
    min-height: 8px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 682px){
    .css3menu a{
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .css3menu {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .css3menu > li{
        float: none;
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }   
    .css3menu > li:first-child{
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

JQUERY:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
        $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
          var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
          if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
            mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
          }
          else {
            mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
            if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
              mainmenu.find('ul').show();
            }
          }
        });

        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

        multiTg = function() {
          cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
          cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
            }
            else {
              $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
            }
          });
        };

        if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
        else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($( window ).width() > 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   title: "Menu",
   format: "multitoggle"
});


});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you should initially show your code so we can check it...please share :)

Comment: Most of the time it is because scroll puts the "cursor" outside the propagated element. Meaning scrolling is not on the window anymore so it is basically like clicking the body of the element to close a modal element.

Comment: There is no need to vote down , because menu is collapsed on mobile device without scrolling itself and this is due to responsiveness,see media query.... –

Answer (score -1):

Looked into that site, it is called responsiveness :), I looked into css code and here it what it looks like

```
    @media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul,
  #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul, ........
```

[image]

Comment: I need to understand the problem u can ping me on skype @avizet2 , because ur menu is always collapsed, I don't understand here how it is related to scroll

Comment: For example if you click on menu(mobile devices) and then say on about new zealand and then on southisland it should come up with multiple sub headings. If you then try to scroll down to see the rest of the sub headings it will collapse @AvinashAgrawal